# UILongPressGesture as IBAction or Property w/ handler method?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

This is just a general "best programming concepts," question, but if someone could answer it for me I would appreciate it. I'm trying to add a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to a button on my viewcontroller. Is is better practice to implement the longpressgesture as an IBAction, or as a property with an included longpressgesture handler method? Or does it not matter?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The button retains the gesture recognizer, and if you want the gesture recognizer to do anything, you give it a target-action pair. There's nothing to think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the button is in your storyboard. What I normally do is create the gesture recognizer in the storyboard as well. I connect the recognizer to the view and then target an @IBAction in my view controller.

It works well for me.

Comment: Ok, awesome. That makes sense, thanks! Just getting into using gestures, appreciate the advice